# Does this sentence make sense in german?

Tags: english-to-german

> Ich habe einen dringenden Anruf von zu Hause bekommen und musste los.

Comment: You could improve your questions by an edit and add, why you are/were doubting the sentence's correctness. Is there a certain word/phrase/grammatical structure that sounds odd to you? This might help people to answer specifically to your problem.

Comment: Why do you think it would not make sense?

Comment: Somebody stop this bot, please.

Comment: @c.p.Did you already flag the OP for mod attention? Their last sock to circumvent the q-ban was nuked after 2 days.

Comment: @c.p. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43701/commonly-used-sentence-for-describing-a-festive-cheerful-moodatmosphere-in-hol#comment106510_43701

Comment: I see... next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. It means: "I got an urgent call from back home and had to leave".